# Is there a way to append data received in multiple post requests

Tags: python, flask, post, parallel-processing, io

I am using a flask server where I would receive data from post request frequently.

Suppose every second I would get new data and process the data, but I don't want to process the incoming data one by one. Instead, I want to process the data received every 5 seconds (in 5 post request).

Is there a way that I can do so?

Comment: What type of data? XML? You could save it to files and just process them one by one every 5 seconds. Depending on the data, you could combine them into a single document but that would depend on the data. You can't just do a naive text append on something like json or xml.

Comment: @tdelaney Thanks for your help and yes it's xml. if saving to file, would pickle file be a good choice?

Comment: Just save the raw XML. Presumably that's the easiest format for processing later. Open the file "wb" for write binary and dump the raw stuff. You may want to build all 5 docs into a single in-core document when you read and process - once again that's data and design dependent.

Comment: @tdelaney Really appreciate that! Will have a try

Answer (score 0):

You can use database - `PostgreSQL` or `Redis` for example to store your data from requests. Create a cron job which will execute every 5 seconds, got data from your storage and process it.